# Hide field on small viewport, click button to show again

Tags: javascript, css, show-hide, viewport

### edit:

The latest working code: http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/DDXrc/9/

---

I have a webpage with a couple of textfields.

These need to be hidden when I reach viewport < 767

When I click on a other div that needs to be visible again.

The html looks like this: (blok1, blok2 etc..)

```
<div class="bull bull-blok1"><a class="show-blok1" href="javascript:void(0)">Show it</a></div>

<div class="blokken blok1">
  <div class="text"><p>Here some text</p></div>
</div>
```

etc..

I guess I can use viewport like below to hide.
But how can I get it working when I click on:  the block:  gets visible?

When reaching viewport > 676 all need to be visible again.

Some CSS:
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){.blokken{display:none;}}
Some JS:
            $(window).resize(function() {
                if ($(window).width() < 767) {
Hide .blokken
When click on .show-blok1 then: show .blok1
                }
                else {
Show all .blokken
                }
            });

Maybe someone can help me out that js part please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the window is re-sized to a width narrower than 767, have code to hide that div, otherwise show the div.

Also have jQuery open that div back up when .bull bull-blok1 is clicked on (href="javascript:showMe()")

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   if($(window).width()<767){$(".blokken blok1").hide()}
   else{$(".blokken blok1").show()}
});


function showMe(){
   jQuery(".blokken blok1").show();
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping. There are still some things which doesn't work. The show button doesn't work, when loading the page < 767 it still shows, then after smallen or extend just 1px it disapears and I don't know how to let it work for blok2. I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4URNe/1/ Maybe anyone can help me out on this? I'm not that good with js.

Comment: jQuery(".blokken blok1").show(); doesn't work either. It needs to be jQuery(".blok1").show();

Comment: Sorry, to answer your first question, it works better (now that I think about it) to set the hide/show If statement inside of a function. Call that function when the window is being resized AND when the page loads, that way it will minimize if it is small enough.

Comment: I edited your fiddle. There were a couple issues with the way to Javascript was ran. You wanted "No wrap - in head" instead of "onLoad". Also you were referencing non existent images.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/DDXrc/6/

I actually forked your fiddle - sorry, and I forgot to add this in my last comment

Comment: Hey Thanks man! I have updated the script and tested with another div.
http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/DDXrc/9/ I dunno if trogge show/hide is an easy task to change instead of hide and not able to show again.

Comment: ..actually, my biggest wish is when I open/show one block, the other ones get closed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/DDXrc/10/

This implements the jQuery toggle() function which allows for opening/closing based on the previous state. It also closes the other divs when one is clicked.

Comment: Thanks man, at first it didn't work on my site, dunno what was wrong, copy past the fiddle js worked.